# Flexbox won't stretch on adding more content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container and it has one header tag and and a div. 
The div consumes the remaining space as the container has 100vh height. In the div there are two more divs everything is working fine but when I add more content to the div on the right and shrink the browser window it overflows the parent div , I'm using flex box so it should wrap the content and the original div's height should increase accordingly to wrap its element but it's not happening.

HTML:

```
    <div class="holder">
     <h1>Work Slides</h1>
     <div class="slides">
     <div class="slide-image">
      <img src='' alt=''>
     </div>
     <div class="slide-content">
      <span>Image Name</span>
      <div>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, magni eos nam in suscipit ex reiciendis, ea repellat cumque minus amet maiores ipsam dolorum dolore mollitia. Architecto eos adipisci blanditiis.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, magni eos nam in suscipit ex reiciendis, ea repellat cumque minus amet maiores ipsam dolorum dolore mollitia. Architecto eos adipisci blanditiis.
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, magni eos nam in suscipit ex reiciendis, ea repellat cumque minus amet maiores ipsam dolorum dolore mollitia. Architecto eos adipisci blanditiis. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span>Page-2</span>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
  margin: 0;
}
.holder{
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.slides{
  background: palevioletred;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide-image, .slide-content{
  max-height: 400px;
  background: orange;  
}
.slide-image img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.slide-content{
  width: 400px;
  padding: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? is it the min-max height/width?

Comment: The main problem here is that you try making a flex column container's flex child to wrap. Flexbox has a bug when it comes to that, where it won't resize its parent when it wraps, hence won't work properly. What should happen? ... should it wrap and start scroll horizontally?, or ...

Answer (score 0):

You have `max-height: 400px;` on `.slide-content`. I believe you only want this on `.slide-image`?

You say

> the original div's height should increase accordingly to wrap its element

but this will not always be true when the parent div has a maximum height.

Comment: yes, but someone the content div is taking up the same height

Comment: You need to change `height: 100vh;` on `.holder` to `min-height: 100vh` so that content in the inner most div can overflow the parent.

Comment: @GadgetBlaster OP want it to wrap, not overflow.